Movie where people are stranded on a plane without knowledge of how they got there
A movie where a few (around 5) people are stranded on a plane. They are from totally different backgrounds. The main character (I think) is a truck driver. There is also a teacher and a former government official. I believe it had something to do with an attack on the White House. Also, none of them knew how they got on the plane. They are the only passengers on the plane.
EDIT :
It is a quite a recent movie, somewhere in the 2000's. And it's a movie, not a tv-series.

The Langoliers (1995), a movie based on a Stephen King novella, is the only thing that instantly comes to mind.

It is quite a new movie, I would say in the 2000's. Plus its a movie, not a tv series. Thanks for the input though :)

"none of them knew how they got on the plane. They are the only passengers on the train." Didja mean plane instead of train?

Oh yes, sorry. Anyways the question is solved.

Got it.  It's Chariot (2013)

Seven strangers wake aboard a passenger jet in mid-flight, with no
  idea how they got there - and no idea where they are headed. Cut off
  from the cockpit and with a dying smartphone as their sole source of
  communication, they learn the U.S. is under a devastating attack...
  and they might be the only survivors.

